# Does SQL Server redistribute data after adding an additional data file?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, performance, performance-tuning

Imagine a database about 30GB in size using 3 data files on the same disk.

Someone told me to have one data file per processor implemented to get full performance on all cpus. So if I now add three more data files, how's the data redistributed to the new files? Do I have to do something?

Comment: I believe the "one data file per processor" rule applies to tempdb only; in general, what's written to tempdb is only used by one connection, so this can be helpful. In your regular data files, data might be needed by multiple connections at the same time, thus no benefit to having separate files for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that datafiles work, any new data will, mostly, get put in the new data file you added. Or in your case the two new data files.

However, SQL Server will not try to re balance your data. This would't make sense either as you will be causing a lot of IO / load on a database for, as far as SQL server knows, no reason.
You can however [rebalance your data by recreating your indexes on a new filegroup while dropping the old indexes](http://sqlmag.com/blog/rebalancing-data-across-files-filegroup). The advantage being that you're allocating space in small chunks, getting unfragmented indexes and generally have more control.

You will however have to do this largely manually. And you'll probably want to create full backups before and after each operation.

Answer (score 2):

Every SQL database has an .mdf file where it stores some basic info about itself and data that is added to tables in the database. It cannot be deleted or replaced.

Optimally for every CPU that a server has there should be a datafile (up to eight), normally these are created by adding .ndf files at the time the database is created.

Trying to keep it simple… we can think of an .mdf or .ndf as physical record (maybe an old school vinyl record that can be rewritten, but runs backwards in to out?) if you only have the .mdf as new data gets added, it gets added farther and farther out.  Occasionally something old is deleted and something new is added in its place but mostly new data is added to the outside.  In this vision a CPU is a record player.  It does not matter how many CPU (record players) you have you can only do things to one record at a time.

So if you have say 4 CPU you want to have 4 data files.   These would be one .mdf and three .ndf.  In theory you can use all 4 CPU to read all 4 at once, work gets done 4 times faster (this is theory, reality varies)

Maybe we have an old system with just the one .mdf and no .ndf.  If we add 3 more .ndf new stuff will start to get written there, but the majority will just stay on the old mdf. There is a bunch of theory that says index rebuilds will move stuff around and it will self-balance over time.  In reality I have rarely seen this happen.  So we have to force it to balance, the best (but not only) way, follows.

- For this example assume 4CPU and 100GB of data.
- Create a new single .ndf named ‘MyDB_Temp.ndf’ or similar, it should be the same size as the current .mdf (100GB)
- Use SHRINKFILE, EMPTYFILE to push everything (except ~5MB of “self” info) to ‘MyDB_Temp.ndf’
- Use SHRINKFILE, 25GB  (specific size) to shrink the original .mdf to 25% of the desired total size
- Create 3 new .ndf files each at the desired size (25GB)
- Use SHRINKFILE, EMPTYFILE to push everything off of ‘MyDB_Temp.ndf’, it will auto balance across all four files, with a mix of old and new data on each.
- Delete ‘MyDB_Temp.ndf’
  *Done, new data gets written across all 4.

Concerns:

- If the system is not having performance issues, don’t worry about, just leave it with the single .mdf
- This is going to be a resource hog, do not do during production time
- Everything gets logged, if simple recover us COMMIT occasionally.  If full recovery run t-log backups
- If you have physical limitations on essentially doubling your database size, you can do it in chunks.  If you have 150GB of space, start with ‘MyDB_Temp’ at 40GB and when it is mostly full, stop and trim 30GB off of the .mdf then add it to .ndf
- There are lots of variables, and no one size fits most solution.
- Sometimes you can balance small databases in a few minutes.  On one occasion, I literally spent months (like 6) moving a little data each night.